# Как из массива строк сделать массив цифр

Tags: php

Есть массив строк нужно сделать из него массив чисел.

```
$mass = array("23","94","64","38");
```

Comment: Что не получается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так:

```
$mass = array("23","94","64","38");
array_map('intval', $mass);
```

Comment: Только результат функции надо присвоить, она же не по ссылке работает.

Comment: Не обязательно))
`print_r( json_decode( json_encode( array_map('intval', $mass) ) ) )`

Comment: вам о том говорят, что `$mass = array_map(...)`

Comment: В вопросе такого условия нет

Comment: Вообще-то есть `сделать из него массив чисел`

Comment: Т.е. сейчас мы массив чисел сделали не из него, а из другого массива?